# Structure of subqueries in mySQL for optimal performance

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, subquery

In MS SQL Server, this query runs normally:

```
SELECT column1
    , (SELECT RelatedColumn1 FROM tbl_related WHERE record_id=a1.record_id) AS pseudocolumn1
    , (SELECT RelatedColumn2 FROM tbl_related WHERE record_id=a1.record_id) AS pseudocolumn2
    , (SELECT RelatedColumn3 FROM tbl_related WHERE record_id=a1.record_id) AS pseudocolumn3
    , (SELECT RelatedColumn4 FROM tbl_related WHERE record_id=a1.record_id) AS pseudocolumn4
     ... [20 or more subqueries here] ...
FROM tbl_primary a1
```

In mySQL, however, this runs TERRIBLY slow--and the performance continues to degrade as you add more subqueries.  I'm sure it has to do with the order of operations under the hood, but my question is how to optimize this query?  How do I pivot all the values from the second table into columns in the result set?  Hoping this doesn't have to be accomplished with multiple JOIN statements (because I don't understand JOINS very well)...?

Comment: "how to optimize this query" --- rewrite it to one join, it is pretty easy

Comment: What do you mean by `How do I pivot all the values from the second table into columns in the result set?`?  Your example *suggests* that They're already different columns in the same row.  Do you mean to state that `RelatedColumn1` is *actually* on a different ***row*** to `RelatedColumn2`?  *[If the existing answers don't give what you need, perhaps you could give the structures of your two example tables?]*

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest you using a `LEFT JOIN` to the related table. Because if you use a `JOIN` then if the tbl_related has no rows for that id then that row will be exclude from the result.

```
SELECT
    column1,
    tbl_related.RelatedColumn1,
    tbl_related.RelatedColumn2,
    tbl_related.RelatedColumn3,
    tbl_related.RelatedColumn4,
    tbl_related.RelatedColumn5
    .....
FROM
    tbl_primary a1
LEFT JOIN tbl_related 
    ON tbl_related.record_id=a1.record_id
```

You know:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT RelatedColumn1 FROM tbl_related WHERE record_id=a1.record_id) 
    AS pseudocolumn1
```

can cause problems in the future. What happens if one of your sub queries returns more then one value? You will probably get an exception saying that the sub query can not return more the one value. So if you are planing to do sub queries like this in the future. At least have a `TOP 1` on them so that the query do not crash. Like this:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT TOP 1 RelatedColumn1 FROM tbl_related WHERE record_id=a1.record_id) 
    AS pseudocolumn1
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL 101:

```
SELECT 
    column1,
    r.RelatedColumn
FROM tbl_primary a1
JOIN tbl_related r
ON r.record_id = a1.recordId
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the `JOIN` clause

```
 SELECT a1.column1,
        rt.RelatedColumn
 FROM tbl_primary a1
 LEFT JOIN tbl_related ON a1.record_id = rt.record_id
```

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is the way to go!

Comment: @aF - assuming he wants to return ALL of the rows from tbl_primary regardless if they match.  My interpretation of the query is that he wants to return rows that match, this opinion is based on the OP stating "record_id=a1.record_id" in their post.

Comment: the query that he has in the question provides all (matching or not).